# website to be indexed in google?

Tags: xml, indexing, xslt

I am not sure what or if I am doing something wrong at the website http://www.jode.com.br

it uses XML and XSL transformation on the browser and after a week it still does not appear in google.
it is normally using google-analytics, I can see the visits etc, but in google i got nothing

I put meta tag in the xsl and in the xml just to make sure the keywords and description would be sucked out by google but nothing...

Do you guys know about this?

Answer (score 2):

The Google bots will only "see" the raw XML from your site, but are expecting HTML.  I don't believe they will perform the dynamic transformation using the XSLT in the processing instruction.

If you want your site to be visible and indexed by Google, then you may need to perform the transformation server-side and return the HTML for Google to index.

If you still want to serve the XML to normal users and have them perform the XSLT transform client-side, then you would need some [server-side logic to identify the Google bots](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=80553) and only performs the transform to return HTML for Google requests.

Comment: they are already indexing it and I didn't ahve to send sitemap for that to happen and the xml transformation is still occuring in the client browser

Answer (score 1):

Your problems include:

1. Using client side XSLT in the first place
2. Only waiting a week
3. Expecting meta elements to have a significant effect

Comment: 1. Is that a problem with google? I saw in other places that it shouldn't.  
2. Should I wait more then? I thought that it would already work after seeing ganalytics working...  
3. SHouldn't the meta help? I thought google used the keywords there and not just the content...